# Number of winners in a tournament

Tags: graph-theory, induction

Suppose there are $2^n$ people in a tournament, and each pair plays one game. Each game has one winner and one loser. How does one show that the winner of the tournament (player with most wins) has at least $2^{n-1}$ wins?

Clearly there are $2^n\choose 2$ $= 2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ total games being played. Each player plays $2^{n}-1$ games. How can i bound the #of wins $k$ of the winner? By def $k$ is more than the number of wins of any other player, hence he is winner

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Martund No, each pair plays one game

Comment: OK I misread, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the winner has less than $2^{n-1}$ wins. Then the number of wins of the winner are atmost $2^{n-1}-1$. Hence, the number of wins of other players are also atmost $2^{n-1}-1$. Hence, the total number of wins in the tournament are atmost $2^n(2^{n-1}-1) = 2^{n-1}(2^n-2)$, which is less than the number of games played, hence contradiction.

Comment: Slick! Thanks! :) is there perhaps a constructive proof?

Comment: @hello_123, I don't know about that.